# How to desolder and solder a small SMD component like this?

Tags: sensor, soldering, surface-mount

I am looking for advice from experienced people for soldering/desoldering a small SMD device such as this one (it's a MAX30102 and it has its pins in the lower face).

I ordered a PCB I designed from a manufacturing company, but they did not have the part and I would like to desolder the needed part from a commercial prototype I bought and solder it onto my PCB.

Would this be possible, or should I buy the part? Will I be able to solder it myself? I also want to know if there is a mounting components service because I guess I will need it for another prototype I am designing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What soldering equipment do you currently have?

Comment: I just have a solder iron but I guess I will be able to get a heating gun from a friend, would it be possible with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this be possible, or should I buy the part? Will I be able to
> solder it myself?

Yeah its possible with a hot air rework station, a magnifying glass or microscope and [some know how](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmX_oLPy08o). Also get [chipquick SMD291](https://www.chipquik.com/datasheets/SMD291.pdf) for flux out of all the years of rework this works best for most prototyping and lead free solders.

You would probably want to practice on [some other boards](https://www.topline.tv/975000_kit.html%27) with QFN (same size pitch as your part).

If that is a bit much there are many board houses that you can hire to do rework.

Comment: Thank you so much Voltage Spike, I learned a lot from your comment, I definetely will research and practice with it!

Comment: Further, I’d suggest fluxing the device and using a soldering iron to put a bit of solder on the pads - basically wipe the solder on each pad. Flux it up along with the footprint on the pcb and use a hot air tool to reflow the device. You’ll need tweezers to hold it in place. The air will need to be around 350C and try to complete the task quickly so you don’t cook the part or pcb. As mentioned,  practice first on a junk pcb to get a feel for the hot air tool.